# Как получить все папки в подпапках с условием совпадения

Tags: python, файлы

Просматриваю все подпапки с помощью такого кода:

```
[x[0] for x in os.walk(scriptFolder)]
```

Я хочу получить путь к папке `Детали`. Чтобы он перебирал массив и искал совпадение.

Как это сделать в одну строку?

```
0:'c:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\backup'
1:'c:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\backup\\yyy'
2:'c:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\backup\\yyy\\Детали'
3:'c:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\backup\\yyy\\Детали\\Сталь 1,5мм'
4:'c:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\backup\\yyy\\Детали\\Сталь 1мм'
5:'c:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\backup\\yyy\\Детали\\Сталь 2мм
```

Comment: что вы хотите получить в результате?

Comment: 2:'c:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\backup\\yyy\\Детали' вот это хочу получить

Comment: @MaxU у меня щас перечисляются папки и файлы, а я хочу из всех папок выбрать ту - в которой есть слово Детали

Answer (score 2):

```
In [92]: from pathlib import Path

In [93]: p = Path("c:/temp/test")
```

все директории:

```
In [98]: list(p.glob("**/*"))
Out[98]:
[WindowsPath('c:/temp/test/xxx'),
 WindowsPath('c:/temp/test/xxx/Documents'),
 WindowsPath('c:/temp/test/xxx/Documents/backup'),
 WindowsPath('c:/temp/test/xxx/Documents/backup/yyy'),
 WindowsPath('c:/temp/test/xxx/Documents/backup/yyy/Детали'),
 WindowsPath('c:/temp/test/xxx/Documents/backup/yyy/Детали и Материалы'),
 WindowsPath('c:/temp/test/xxx/Documents/backup/yyy/Детали/Сталь 1мм'),
 WindowsPath('c:/temp/test/xxx/Documents/backup/yyy/Детали/Сталь 2мм'),
 WindowsPath('c:/temp/test/xxx/Documents/backup/yyy/Детали и Материалы/Прокат 1мм')]
```

выбираем только директории называющиеся `Детали`:

```
In [95]: list(p.glob("**/Детали"))
Out[95]: [WindowsPath('c:/temp/test/xxx/Documents/backup/yyy/детали')]
```

выбираем директории содержащие слово `Детали`:

```
In [100]: list(p.glob("**/Детали*"))
Out[100]:
[WindowsPath('c:/temp/test/xxx/Documents/backup/yyy/Детали'),
 WindowsPath('c:/temp/test/xxx/Documents/backup/yyy/Детали и Материалы')]
```

Чтобы получить путь в виде строки:

```
In [115]: res = [x.as_posix() for x in p.glob("**/Детали")]

In [116]: res
Out[116]: ['c:/temp/test/xxx/Documents/backup/yyy/детали']
```